# How does blockchaininfo find out the difficulty?

Tags: client, difficulty, blockchain.info, live-data

Do they have a client installed on their servers that pulls the info out of block headers? How does it do it? What's the command?

Answer (score 2):

Blockchain.info definitely has a client installed on their servers, that's where they get all the block data from. I heard they're using a fork of BitcoinJ.

In the Bitcoin-qt daemon, you can get the difficulty of the latest block with the getdifficulty command, and you can get complete information about every block, including the difficulty, with getblock.

Comment: How would I do it without a UI, say, if I installed bitcoind on my server?

Comment: If you can access it with a CLI, you can go to the daemon directory and run bitcoind.exe with the required command as a parameter. Other than that there's something called JSON-RPC but I don't really know what that is.

Comment: Drats, I have a Mac . . .

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull: Are you talking about a computer you have locally? I don't know how Macs work, but doesn't it have a command prompt?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull Open up spotlight and type in "terminal" for the command line.  If your bitcoind instance has JSON-RPC enabled through config you can use CURL to access the data

Comment: Or just open the regular QT client and click help : Debug Window : Console.  You can use most of the commands right there if youre running 7.x